# How can I add a CSS animation to this button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I have a set of 4 accordian tabs that's height increases when hovered on. I am trying to add a CSS animation so there is a smooth transition between it's inactive height to its height when hovered on. I would like it to be a smooth transition as well.

So far, I have tried using an animation for the height inside the object class:

```
button.accordions:hover {
  transition: height 0.5s ease;

  height: 75px;
}
```

This results in the buttons not changing height at all when hovered on.

Here is a link to my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5d3j296s/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things!
In your fiddle, you don't have any units for your transition.  It's just `transition: height 0.5 ease;`, it's missing the 's' for the timer.

Second, you need to have a starting point for your height - it doesn't transition from auto.  So, for example, set `height: 56px;` on your `button.accordions` class as your starting point.

If you want the transition to grow *and* shrink, then move the `transition: height 0.5s ease;` out of `:hover` and stick it on the base `button.accordions` class.

Answer (score 1):

The `transition` property should be set inside the `button.accordions` selector, not inside the `button.accordions:hover` selector.

```
button.accordions {
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease;
}
button.accordions:hover {
    max-height: 75px;
}
```

Comment: To state that one should not set `transition` inside the `:hover` rule is wrong. It depends on what one want to achieve, hence both rules can have the property set.

Comment: I actually meant that for this problem in particular, the transition property should be set out of the hover state. @LGSon the accepted answer also gives that tip (i.e. move the transition property out of the hover state).

Comment: Where the, in this case, `transition` is declared is not the reason OP's code doesn't work, animation using `auto` is, and the syntax error (omit a unit value), and your answer implies it has to do with only where it is declared. Furthermore, you changed the code from `height` to `max-height` w/o any explanation what so ever, making the answer even more confusing.